# QuickFix Python, CompositeLogFactory not available?

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, quickfixn

In Java or C# you could use compositelogfactory to use both screenlogfactory and filelogfactory to write logs to both a log file and to the screen

```
QuickFix.ILogFactory logFactory = new QuickFix.CompositeLogFactory(settings);
logFactory = new CompositeLogFactory(
 new LogFactory[] { new ScreenLogFactory(settings),
 new FileLogFactory(settings)});
```

However in the Python version (SWIG C++ version), I can't find the CompositeLogFactory. Is this not available or is it possible to achieve the same functionality in a different (but similar) way through Python QuickFix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python version simply wraps the C++ lib in Python bindings.

The C++ version doesn't have a CompositeLogFactory, so the Python-wrapped version doesn't have it either.

Comment: Thanks, so it is not possible to have both the logfactories active in quickfix cpp/python??

Comment: I don't know if Python/SWIG allows you to write a Python class that is a subclass of a C++ class.  But if you can, then it would be pretty easy to write your own implementation of the Log interface that delegates to instantiations of ScreenLog and FileLog.

Comment: I don't know how to do it but if you have a sample I would be happy to receive it

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a python programmer.

Comment: And my cpp knowledge is not at a level that I could write this. Probably the drawback of using swig.